# 2000 Honda Accord won't start when engine is warm

Tags: honda, starting, accord, egr

I have a 2000 Honda Accord.  A few years ago I started having an issue with the car not wanting to start once the engine was warmed up.  I finally took it to the dealership and they diagnosed that none of my sparkplugs were firing and the EGR valve was stuck open.  They also informed me that the bulb to my check engine light was missing.  With all three items repaired, the check engine light was still on.

Took car to Autozone, they diagnosed P1457 and told me not to worry.  My car ran fine for about 9 months and then I started facing the same problem again. Took back to Autozone, P1457 and another code for the EGR valve showed.  Replaced EGR valve again and less than a month later, the start problem is back.  Took back to Autozone and the only code is P1457.  I'm at loss.

Would the P1457 cause the car not to start?  Seems odd since the code has been in place for over a year.  I can smell gas so I know that I need to figure out if it is the cannister or solenoid but my main concern is trying to figure out why my car won't start once it's warm.  I can either wait 20-30 minutes and try again or I can keep pumping and feathering the gap pedal until the rough idle smooths out--that takes about 5 minutes.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Many Honda vehicles of that age have "hot restart" problem due to a faulty fuel relay.  The relay is usually inside the cabin, under the dash (I have no experience on the Accord, though).

It should at least be possible to test if you have access to the relay.

Examples: [Civic relay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F2OsgXmshI) [Honda relay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CMZ4g8n0FQ) (Relay portion starts after about 5:30 on the second video).