# Honda Civic 2005 doesn't restart after 10-15 km

Tags: starting, civic

When I first start my 2005 Honda Civic, it starts. But, when I run 10-15 km and stop the engine, it won't start anymore.  I have to wait 15-30 minutes before it will start again.

The alternator and battery are good.

1. What could be causing this?
2. How do I diagnose this?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to restart? Nothing? Sputter? Does anything happen when you reach that 10-15km mark? Does it restart fine within that range?

Comment: Does it only happen after 10-15km, or does it also happen if you drive farther? What do you mean by "won't start" -- won't turn over, or turns over but won't fire? It sounds like it's possibly heat-related, try raising your hood after you park and see if that helps. It could be a bad starter, a bad relay, or possibly an issue with the fuel system.

Comment: Very similar to known fuel relay problems.  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/2000-honda-accord-wont-start-when-engine-is-warm/16481