# Honda Accord 1.8 Sport VTEC will not always fire and start

Tags: electrical, honda, starting, accord, intermittent-problems

A week ago, went to start the car and it cranked over fine with battery but would not start.

A few days later, after charging up the battery, I tried again and it would not fire. Called AA and he connected a booster battery as he had to crank the engine for long periods after flooding the engine. Finally it started and he advised changing plugs. New plugs fitted it and it worked for a week then the next morning it wouldn't fire. Recharged the battery but no success. The battery is only a year old and cranks the engine well. What else could be intermittently causing it not to fire?

Comment: Please supply the year made. I would guess that the ignition coil is failing.

Comment: It was registered in 2002

Comment: Check relay?  mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/2000-honda-accord-wont-start-when-engine-is-warm/

Comment: @BowlOfRed https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/2000-honda-accord-wont-start-when-engine-is-warm/

Answer (score 1):

things to check:

- does it have spark. pull a sparkplug and ground it or hook a timing light up to a cable and see if you have spark
- do you smell fuel out the exhaust pipe after cranking? if you do you may have a flooding issue
- is your fuel pump turning on? you might want to test fuel line pressure.
- are your fuel filters clean?